# text not changing in a TextView while doing Layout Inflater

Tags: android, layout-inflater

in my app when the activity get loaded, i am doing the following

```
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
layoutToAdd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

for(i=0; i<num;i++)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, null);
    layoutToAdd.addView(view);
}
```

The value of num differs for each time.

In my LayoutInflater layout i have a text view, edit text and a button.

Now they are shown according to the number of times mentioned in `num`, now for each time i want the text and button name to be changed. How to set the text for TextView and Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set them after you inflate the layout

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, null);
TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textviewid); //id defined in camera.xml
Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonid);      //id defined in camera.xml
tv.setText();
b.setText();
layoutToAdd.addView(view);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you pls say me how to find that a particular button is been clicked in the layout inflater.....

Comment: you can setTag() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object) for your button (according to num for example `view.findViewById(R.id.buttonid).setTag(new Integer(num));`) when you inflate it and in OnClickListener get this tag. `public void onClick(View v){Integer buttonNum = v.getTag();}`

Comment: thanx... i have one more doubt about Inflater. is it possible to create the inflate view both in horizontal and vertical directions at a single time

Comment: `TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);`

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest it,you should create an xml file containing just a LinearLayout.

Then programaticall,you should create TextViews,EditTexts and Buttons and add it to LinearLayout.

You can set different properties of those components like below:

Here is example of setting TextView's properties.For rest of the components,you can set the same.

```
TextView tv=new TextView(context);
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_bg);
tv.setPadding(20, 5, 40, 5);
tv.setText("set your text");
tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setId(id);//where id is an integer which should be unique for each TextView

layout.addView(tv);
```

Also you need to create and add all these three component inside the for loop,providing unique ids depending on i you use to iterate the loop!And you can have a String array for textviews and buttons to set their names in for loop,which would be easier for you for passing the string you like to set to them in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You must store the reference of the view inflated and store in a List then when you want to modify simply list.get(2).findViewById(R.id.textbox_id).

Hope it help.